# Laravel eloquent builder to raw

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sum, laravel-8

Can any one convert the below given raw query to laravel eloquent query

```
SELECT `from`,`to`,`from`+`to` as total FROM `chats`;
```

i have tried select raw , and db raw but it is not working for the sum to from and to as total

Comment: Show us what you tried as well

Comment: DB::table("chats")
        ->select("from", "to",DB::raw('from+to as total'))
        ->get();

Comment: That should work. What are you getting? How are you using that resut?

Comment: i am getting error

Comment: Is the error a secret?

Answer (score 2):

i find the way to do it

```
Chat::select('id','from', 'to', 'message','read','created_at',DB::raw('`from` + `to` as total'))->get();
```

it's working fine thanx for your support guys.